# momentum rotation of image in iOS

Tags: ios, rotation, momentum

I'm new to iOS graphics and animation and would like to know to how to accomplish the effect of momentum rotation of an image upon flick as seen in the video below.

`http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZIQs-OWgkgI` (now broken)

Even when not flicked the images have a nice sway.

Thanks.

Comment: Start by busting out your old physics text book

Comment: Personally I'd use a physics engine. Might seem over the top at first but saves me writing the physics myself!

Comment: James, Are you using Chipmunk or a different physics engine?

Answer (score 1):

That is pretty slick. It is rotating the view around a point (center of top) and then changing the amount of time it takes to rotate algorithmically, reversing when appropriate. I can't give you code, but I think if you watch this video demo from Prof. Hegarty you will have the tools you need. He rotates around a point outside the view - you can simply rotate around the edge of the view (and don't shrink the view). Check it out:

Part 1: http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/node/291

Part 2: http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/node/293

You'll definitely want to download the videos off iTunes U (free), as there is a lot of explanation.

Good luck,

Damien

Answer (score 0):

I checked with the author of this and was informed that it was implemented using the Box2D physics library. I'm going to give that a shot. Thanks for the responses!

Answer (score 0):

```
//this code can be used to rotate an image having both back and front 

   rotate = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [rotate addTarget:self action:@selector(rotate1)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        rotate.frame = CGRectMake(137.5, 245, 45, 46);
        [rotate setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"viewing.png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.view addSubview:rotate];

     int count;
     count=0;

    -(void)rotate1
    {


        count=count+1;
        NSLog(@"rotate");
        [UIView transitionWithView:imagecircle    // use the forView: argument
                          duration:1          // use the setAnimationDuration: argument
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
         // check UIViewAnimationOptions for what options you can use
                        animations:^{         // put the animation block here
                            imagecircle.image = imagecircle.image;
                        }
                        completion:NULL];

        if(count%2==0)
        {
            NSLog(@"image.str.%@",appDelegate.imageNameString);
            [imagecircle setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:appDelegate.imageNameString]];
            [labellocation removeFromSuperview];
            [labeldate removeFromSuperview];
            [self.imagecircle addSubview:labelfrom];

        }
        else
        {
             [imagecircle setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TGP_BACK.png"]];
             [labelfrom removeFromSuperview];
             [self.imagecircle addSubview:labellocation];
             [self.imagecircle addSubview:labeldate];
        }



    }
```